# Confusion in Json Structure

Tags: json, gson, unmarshalling

I am creating a json configuration to create a dashboard with multiple widgets.
I will read that json file and create pojo from it using Gson. The structure of the Java classes is like:

```
public class Widgets {
  //Some other variables
  private List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
  //some more variables and methods
}
public interface Widget{}
public class MeterWidget implements Widget{
  //some meter widget variables
}
public class GraphWidget implements Widget{
  //some graph widget variables
}
```

Now I want to declare widgets in json with multiple widgets of the same kind possible. Something like below:

```
{
  "widgets": [
    {
      "meterWidget": {
      },
      "meterWidget": {
      },
      "graphWidget": {
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know this json is not correct as we can't have multiple items with the same name(meterWidget in this case) inside a single object, but I can't think of any structure that will help me with the class structure above. Also having widgets in an array is not necessary as I am not maintaining any order in this structure. Please help.

Thanks
Raman

Answer (score 1):

You could have the type be a parameter in json like this:

```
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "meterWidget",
            "someParam": "stuff"
        },
        {
            "type": "meterWidget",
            "someParam": "stuff"
        }
    ]
}
```